# Why can't I change the reason for closing-vote of a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have voted to close a question because it was confusing and it wasn't clear what the question exactly was about. After reading my comment, the author edited his/her question and clarified it. I answered the question in the next comment, which seems to have satisfied the OP. Since the question was not really programming related (identifying a file as email), I wanted to vote for closing it again, but for a different reason. However, I cannot vote for closing the question anymore. What is the reason for that?

[image: Pop-up with no closing option available anymore]

Related question: [Email Content - Value without key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311672/email-content-value-without-key?noredirect=1)